# Генератор цифр с префиксом

Tags: c#

Хочу сгенерировать цифры

```
12345000001
12345000002
12345000003
```

Префикс здесь 12345. А оставшаяся часть это то что нужно увеличивать. Не совсем понятно как инкрементировать число 000001. Какой тип для него задать?

Comment: Если префикс неизменен, то можно начать с 12345000000 и проверять когда достигнет 999999, уточните условие пжл

Comment: Нужно уточнить - вам на выходе нужны такие числа, или такие строки. Если числа, надо брать 64 битные переменные и сразу прибавлять туда префикс, умноженный на 10^6. Если строки, вам подойдет ответ @Alex Krass. Только не вздумайте клеить строки, а потом переводить их в числа.

Comment: Как минимум речь идет о числах, а не цифрах.

Comment: @NickVolynkin вот тут принципиальный вопрос, и правка как раз может искажать желание автора - если он желает получить такой набор цифр, и далее работать как со строкой (что первоначально было в тексте), тогда замена "цифр" на "числа" все переставляет с ног на голову.

Comment: Если числа, то это же вообще банально... `for(Int64 i=12345000000; i<12345000999; i++) Console.WriteLine(i);`

Comment: @gbg: ок, откатил. Сомневаюсь, что дождемся уточняющей правки от автора.

Comment: @AlexKrass числа, числа. Посмотрите, что он благодаря вашему ответу со склейкой строк натворил - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/452397/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB

Comment: @gbg ну так обычное дело, когда вопрос без контекста и уточнений. Кстати, в итоге ему все таки нужна строка как я понимаю(а может и нет), но очень много лишних конвертаций.

Comment: Очень редко бывает, когда строка, которая выглядит как число, и правда нужна в виде строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться форматированием строк.

```
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("12345{0,6:D6}", i));
}
```