# Как ускорить многопоточный цикл

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Проверяю число в методе `isGood()`. Его время выполенения `4821мс`. Цикл работает ну очень долго. Спецом убрал запись в list. Может есть более быстрый способ?

```
Parallel.For(0, 1000000000, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8 }, count =>
            {
                var tmp = Convert.ToInt32(binBox.Text) + count.ToString("D10");
                long cardNumber = Convert.ToInt64(tmp);

                if (isGood(cardNumber.ToString()))
                {
                   // genNumbers.Add(cardNumber.ToString()); 
                }

            });

 private  bool IsGood(string number)
        {
            int[] DELTAS = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0 };
            int checksum = 0;
            char[] chars = number.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = chars.Length - 1; i > -1; i--)
            {
                int j = ((int)chars[i]) - 48;
                checksum += j;
                if (((i - chars.Length) % 2) == 0)
                    checksum += DELTAS[j];
            }

            return ((checksum % 10) == 0);
        }
```

Comment: Брутфорсите номера кредиток? Ну-ну.

Comment: Код `isGood()` в студию. Как вы сами сказали, именно этот метод съедает почти все время в итерации.

Answer (score 1):

Избавьтесь от склейки строк, она гораздо медленнее арифметики.
Я так понимаю, вам нужно прибавлять к номеру бокса значение итератора, умноженное на 100 и число 10. Вот и прибавляйте:

```
long cardNumber = Convert.ToInt64(binBox.Text) + count*100+10;
```

Comment: Эта строка в неглавном потоке вообще должна вылетать — `binBox.Text` наверняка UI-контрол, к которому можно обращаться только из UI-потока.

Comment: Время склейки строк ничтожно по сравнению с тем, что метода `isGood()`, по словам автора, выполняется больше 4-х секунд.

Answer (score 1):

нет смысла переводить число в строку

```
if (isGood(cardNumber.ToString()))
```

и сразу же после этого парсить строку и извлекать отдельные цифры:

```
char[] chars = number.ToCharArray();
for (int i = chars.Length - 1; i > -1; i--)
{
    int j = ((int)chars[i]) - 48;
```

передавайте cardNumber как long. перепишите цикл на что-то вроде

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) // всегда 16 цифр - это же номер кредитки?
{
    int j = number % 10;
    number = number / 10;

    ...
}
```

и кстати, брутфорсить номера кредиток - достаточно бесполезное занятие.

Comment: +нет смысла каждый раз делать `Convert.ToInt32(binBox.Text)` (кроме того, что оно может упасть).

Answer (score 0):

Думаю дополнительно стоит записать `binBox.Text` в какую-нибудь локальную переменную перед циклом и работать с ней. Есть предположение, что обращение к локальнйо переменной будет быстрее, чем к контролу, если binBox это какой-то контрол.